# How to Add Dynamic Text Box inside child gridview in nested gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How to Add Dynamic Text Box inside child gridview
?Below screen shot will give clear picture of my question.I am unable to add on second row which is shown in screen shot.

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEKtc.png)

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried? How is the behavior of what you tried different from the behavior you are expecting. Please always include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when you ask a question on SO.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion .I want to add new text box on every click of Add New Row button.Here is nested gridview and when i clicked on Add New Row button  nested gridview disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Adding Dynamic Rows in GridView with TextBoxes

```html
<asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true"
                             AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 3">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <FooterTemplate>
                 <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

Your Binding Code

```
 private void SetInitialRow(){

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
        dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column3"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        //Store the DataTable in ViewState
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

        Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
        Gridview1.DataBind();
}
```

Page Load Event Code

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack){
            SetInitialRow();  
        }
```

Running the codes above will give us this output below:

[image]

method for generating the rows when clicking the Button

```
private void AddNewRowToGrid(){

        int rowIndex =0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");

                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                    drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1; 
                    drCurrentRow["Column1"] = box1.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Column2"] = box2.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Column3"] = box3.Text;

                    rowIndex++;
                }

                //add new row to DataTable
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                //Store the current data to ViewState
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                //Rebind the Grid with the current data
                Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                Gridview1.DataBind();
           }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }

        //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
        SetPreviousData();
}
```

Setting up previous Data

```
private void SetPreviousData(){

        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");


                    box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();
                    box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();
                    box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();

                    rowIndex++;

                }
            }
        }
}
```

Button click event Code

```
protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        AddNewRowToGrid();
}
```

[image]

For Detail Tutorial Visit : [geekswithblock](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/06/04/adding-dynamic-rows-in-gridview-with-textboxes.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But i want to generate  text box when Add New Row button is clicked .

Comment: what will be the value of  DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"]; when i  am adding text box inside child gridview which is inside second row of parent gridview?@Shaikh Aamir

Comment: if u had known about session management u would know that it is to store state of ur previously stored data

Comment: Yes i know about ViewState but i am having problem in keeping the value in view state.example. i have created 5 rows in child gridview and at that time my (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"] will be 5 records but when i click on second row of parent gridview at that time i have only first row(one records on (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable") on child gridview.so how can i keep that value in view state.

Comment: please kindly request you to view this screen shot. http://i.stack.imgur.com/tEKtc.png

Comment: u have to keep subtopic row in that